# 2D interpolation of array of values

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate between 2 arrays and I don't know how to this.
I have 3 arrays of values:
two values array:
$[a_1,a_2,a_3, \dots,a_n]$,$[b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n]$ 
and each of the arrays has a value $z_1$, $z_2$ respectively. 
I also have a target array: $[c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n]$ 
I want to interpolate between $z_1$ and $z_2$ according to $a$ & $b$ arrays and find the appropriate $z$ value to the $c$ array.

How can it be done? 
I hope I'm clear enough as my English is not perfect.